# Array in 'while' loop

Tags: php, html, arrays

I'm stuck

I'll explain the concept; I retrieve the data ( a date) of a query that I modify using a while, after I modify the date correctly, then I initiate a switch.
In this switch I want to add the date into a table which displays 'In the year 2017,' + the dates, but in this collection I want to insert my date and it does not work.
If I initialize a variable example: $x = "15:06"; It works. Help!

Here is the corresponding code: the box $annee_selectionne does not work

```
 $req_public_holiday = $bdd - > query('SELECT * FROM public_holiday');


 while ($donnees_public_holiday = $req_public_holiday - > fetch()) {

   $format_date = date('Y.m.d', strtotime($donnees_public_holiday['date']));
   $var1 = explode('.', $format_date);

   $year_selectionne = $var1[0];
   $month_selectionne = $var1[1];
   $day_selectionne = $var1[2];
   $date_x = $day_selectionne.
   ":".$month_selectionne;


   switch ($year_selectionne) {
     case 2013:
       $free_day = array('01:01', '01:04', '01:05', '08:05', '09:05', '14:07', '15:08', '01:11', '11:11', '25:12');
       break;
     case 2014:
       $free_day = array('01:01', '21:04', '01:05', '08:05', '29:05', '09:06', '14:07', '15:08', '01:11', '11:11', '25:12');
       break;
     case 2015:
       $free_day = array('01:01', '06:04', '01:05', '08:05', '14:05', '25:05', '14:07', '15:08', '01:11', '11:11', '25:12');
       break;
     case 2016:
       $free_day = array('01:01', '28:03', '01:05', '05:05', '14:07', '15:08', '01:11', '11:11', '25:12');
       break;
       problem-- >
     case $year_selectionne:
       $free_day = array($day_selectionne.':'.$month_selectionne);
       break;
     default:
       $free_day = array('01:01', '01:05', '08:05', '14:07', '15:08', '01:11', '11:11', '25:12');
       break;
   }

 }
```

Comment: you should add some html and maybe some css too.. you can go to https://www.jsfiddle.net and put all your code there. Post the jsfiddle URL here .. as a comment or edit your question and insert it.

Comment: i don't understand - what is the problem with initialising a variable; you should initialise your variables or else they will be undefined? Do all values  come out the same or what is the problem?

Comment: there is also phpfiddle.org for making php fiddles

Answer (score 0):

I believe a better approach will be to create a variable for the month:date value you want to add in the array and instead to a push to it (PHP array_push())

Just create a $month_date variable of type array() and then push into it using the method.
You might want to have a if..else check to see if that variable already exists.

Comment: @igor-paiva has shown the same thing that I suggested using array_push()
That must be helpful nosperato. :)

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code and used the function `array_push()`.

```
 $req_public_holiday = $bdd - > query('SELECT * FROM public_holiday');


 while ($donnees_public_holiday = $req_public_holiday - > fetch()) {

   $format_date = date('Y.m.d', strtotime($donnees_public_holiday['date']));
   $var1 = explode('.', $format_date);

   $year_selectionne = $var1[0];
   $month_selectionne = $var1[1];
   $day_selectionne = $var1[2];
   $date_x = $day_selectionne.
   ":".$month_selectionne;


   switch ($year_selectionne) {
     case 2013:
       $free_day = array('01:01', '01:04', '01:05', '08:05', '09:05', '14:07', '15:08', '01:11', '11:11', '25:12');
       break;
     case 2014:
       $free_day = array('01:01', '21:04', '01:05', '08:05', '29:05', '09:06', '14:07', '15:08', '01:11', '11:11', '25:12');
       break;
     case 2015:
       $free_day = array('01:01', '06:04', '01:05', '08:05', '14:05', '25:05', '14:07', '15:08', '01:11', '11:11', '25:12');
       break;
     case 2016:
       $free_day = array('01:01', '28:03', '01:05', '05:05', '14:07', '15:08', '01:11', '11:11', '25:12');
       break;

     case date('Y'):
       $free_day = array_push($free_day, $day_selectionne.':'.$month_selectionne);
       break;
     default:

       $free_day = array('01:01', '01:05', '08:05', '14:07', '15:08', '01:11', '11:11', '25:12');
       break;
   }

 }
```

I hope help you.